# Overwrite file and apply file system rights of overwritten files?

Tags: filesystems, backup, restore, access-control

I backed up some linux configuration files to a windows machine, so the file system rights were lost. Now I would like to restore my backed up configuration by overwriting the configuration currently present on the linux machine. Is there a command like "overwrite configuration.conf with backup/configuration.conf and apply the file rights of the overwritten configuration.conf to the new configuration.conf" ? Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chmod` to first copy permissions to the backup.

```
 chmod --reference <reference> <target>
```

1. Copy backup file to linux system using a different name like *file.bak*

   `cp /mnt/windows/FILE  /etc/directory/FILE.bak`
2. apply the permissions from the original file

   `chmod --reference /etc/directory/FILE /etc/directory/FILE.bak`
3. mv backup to target

   `mv /etc/directory/FILE.bak /etc/directory/FILE`

Put all this in a for-loop. 
`chown`can be used similarly to copy the owner and group from a reference file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints! Selected as answer :-) Except someone tells em, hey there's a aprameter to cp/mv to do this all in just on step :P